# Dynamically add a select dropdown menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu and other input fields dynamically. So far it works fine adding Text input field, but it does nothing with Select input (dropdown).

This is the HTML:

```
<form method="POST"> 
    <div id="dynamicInput"></div>
    <input type="button" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" value="Add inputs"/>
</form>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
function addInput(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = 
   "<input type='text' id='name'>"+
   '<select id="age">
       <option value="18">18</option>
       <option value="18">18</option>
   </select>';
   document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Peace.

Comment: are you missing literal quotes in the real copy or just on here?

Comment: @dandavis I've tried also this with no success:
    newdiv.innerHTML = 
   "<input type='text' id='name'>"+
   "<select id='age'>
       <option value='18'>18</option>
       <option value='18'>18</option>
   </select>";

Answer (score 1):

I bet your console tells you something like *unexpected token*.
Concatenation of a multiline string requires escaping.

You can do:

```
myVar = "hello \
    sir!";
```

or concatenate each line:

```
myVar = "hello " + 
    "sir!";
```